# Getting issue while updating cart price

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

Hi i am trying to update cart price based on a system config option using observer but its not working below is my code..........

**CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php**

```
class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_request;
    private   $_jsonSerializer;
    protected $Helper;
    
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer,
        \Envision\Ecomm\Helper\Data $Helper
    )
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_jsonSerializer    = $jsonSerializer;
        $this->Helper = $Helper;
    }
 
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        //for price update based on subscription price 
        $item1 = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');           
        $item1 = ( $item1->getParentItem() ? $item1->getParentItem() : $item1 );
        $customHelper = $this->Helper->getPlanPrice("general/quantity_ranges/ranges" , $custom["price"]);

        $testPrice = $item->getPrice(); //product original price is here 
        $price = $testPrice + $customHelper;
        $item1->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item1->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item1->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $logger->info("Info". $customHelper);
            
    }
}
```

**Data.php**

```
public function getPlanPrice($config_path, $plan){

        $customprice = $this->getConfig($config_path);
         foreach($customprice as $custom){
            if($plan == $custom["plan"]){
                return $custom["price"];
            }
         }

    }
```

please tell me what am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

check below code is work for me

```
    $this->cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); 

    $product = $this->_product->load(22);

    $customPrice = 10000;

    $productItem = $this->cart->getItemByProduct($product);
    $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
    $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
    //Enable super mode on the product.
    $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Comment: add this line in your code and load product then change price $this->cart->getItemByProduct($product);

Comment: my code is also working when am passing the static price but with helper am getting issue we cannot add this item to your cart\

Comment: there is some issue with the way am calling the helper i guess?

Comment: I think so, print plan price in logger check is correctly getting or not